# Request hostname is invalid: request sent from a Docker container to a web application running on localhost

Tags: docker, curl, localhost

I have such docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  sequence-counts-loading:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
```

Here is the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.11.2-bullseye

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

# Prevents container from stopping
# See also: https://devopscube.com/keep-docker-container-running/
ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I am starting it with `docker-compose up --build` after which I am using `Dev Containers` `VS Code` extension to connect to the running container. I open up terminal there and run: `curl host.docker.internal` which seems to be working because I am getting the response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IIS Windows</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#0072C6;
        margin:0;
}

#container {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        }

a img {
        border:none;
}

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp;clcid=0x409"><img src="iisstart.png" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But then I am trying to `curl` a running application on another port and it is always giving me `400` error page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

e.g.: `curl http://host.docker.internal:6666` or `curl http://host.docker.internal:6666` or `curl http://host.docker.internal:6666/ajax.ashx?cmd=lib.mapping` while locally in any browser I can run `http://localhost:6666/ajax.ashx?cmd=lib.mapping` without any issues and it returns a json object. What could be the reasons for such behavior? What could I try doing?

I have also tried to add port mapping (`docker-compose.yaml`):

```
ports:
  - '6666:6666'
```

But when I try to start the container its refusing to do that giving an error:

```
ERROR: for sequence-counts-loading  Cannot start service sequence-counts-loading: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:6666 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6666: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

> Update

We are using `Norton` on `Windows 11`, so we created a rule (`Firewall` -> `Traffic Rules`) to allow a range of ports where my localhost application is running, restarted computer, but it didn't fix the issue. We can't totally disable Norton and test it without it. I wonder if regular `ubuntu` image has any firewall settings too?.. The issue can be easily reproduced by:

```
docker run --rm -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Then:

```
apt update
apt install curl
curl host.docker.internal:6666/ajax.ashx?cmd=lib.mapping
```

when the web app is running at `localhost:6666`. So, if Norton is actually blocking it, we need to know then how to allow it. Setting traffic rules does not seem to be working.

Comment: Your container does absolutely nothing, since you have its `ENTRYPOINT` hard-coded that way, and you can probably safely delete it.  The question actually seems to be about the HTTP server you're trying to contact; do you have a [mcve] describing that server, and in particular, will it be sensitive to an HTTP `Host:` header (does it do some sort of host-based routing where `localhost` and `host.docker.internal` will behave differently)?

Comment: No, it has python code. I need to make sure that I can ping a localhost app. This is for development purposes on Windows using `Dev Containers` extension. I didn't expose ports, but even if I do - docker container wouldn't start maybe because of elevated priveleges issue, not sure.

Comment: As part of constructing a MRE, does this behave any differently if you `docker run --rm -it ubuntu /bin/bash`, without building the image or using your local code at all?  (Are the Dockerfile and Compose setup required to demonstrate the issue?)

Comment: Yeah, if you have some application running on a port on `Windows 11` and you use `VS Code` and `Dev Containers` extension, it is reproducible using just `Dockerfile` and the `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: Fully reproducible with just the command you posted: `docker run --rm -it ubuntu /bin/bash`. Returning `400` when querying anything running on port on `localhost`. If we expose port: `docker run --rm -it -p 6666:6666 ubuntu /bin/bash` its giving me an error: `Error response from daemon: Ports are not available`. So, seems like nothing is needed, neither `Dockerfile`, nor `docker-compose.yaml`.

Comment: It looks like `catch-22` to me then: to send a request from Docker container to a url on a port we need to expose this port, but if something is running on this port that is just not possible, and then how to send the request then?

Comment: You do not need to publish ports to make outbound requests.  Based on what you've shown, I think the problem is almost certainly in the host Web server configuration, and it has little to do with Docker or VSCode.

Comment: What kind of configs should be changed on windows 11?